# Vim GitGutter deletes unstaged hunks

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm having some weird problems with my [GitGutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter).
If I have added some lines to my code:

```
1 oldline1
2+newline1
3+newline2
4 oldline2
```

and then I close the file (wq) and reopen it. it looks like this:

```
1 oldline1
2+---- 2 lines: newline 1-----------------------
4 oldline2
```

Why is it doing this and how can I prevent/resolve this problem in the future?

Thanks in advance for any tips!
Edvin

Comment: That looks like vim has folded the lines - typically this is for hiding bits of a file so you can concentrate on the important bits. In code, you might fold functions and classes and only open the ones you're interested in examining, or in a diff it'll fold big chunks of unchanged code. Try navigating to the line and typing `zo` to open the fold. As for why vim thinks that's an appropriate thing to fold, that will depend on what file type vim thinks the file is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and great comment! Truly a life saver for vim rookies like myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is called a "fold", it is a compressed view that shows multiple similar line into a single line. Nothing is deleted, it is only hidden.

You can read `:help fold-commands` from inside vim.

The most useful and basic commands are :

- `zo` : to open a fold (while being on the active line)
- `zc` : to close the fold again

Similarly if you want to apply it on the whole file you can use `zO` and `zC`.

I am not familiar with GitGutter but if you don't want to use any fold, search for that keyword in the configuration file (if there is any).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Very informative. I didn't even know about folds in vim.